# A1 Academia Server Deployment Error

Tags: java, jboss

I am trying to install A1 Academia server but as I start the server, it shuts down again. Please someone help me. Find the log output below:

```
06:35:50,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting JBoss (Microcontainer)...
06:35:50,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] Release ID: JBoss [The Oracle] 5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221634)
06:35:50,743 DEBUG [ServerImpl] Using config: org.jboss.bootstrap.BaseServerConfig@702fad
06:35:50,743 DEBUG [ServerImpl] Server type: class org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl
06:35:50,743 DEBUG [ServerImpl] Server loaded through: org.jboss.bootstrap.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader
06:35:50,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] Bootstrap URL: null
06:35:50,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] Home Dir: C:\academia-server-5.1.0
06:35:50,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] Home URL: file:/C:/academia-server-5.1.0/
06:35:50,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] Library URL: file:/C:/academia-server-5.1.0/lib/
06:35:50,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] Patch URL: null
06:35:50,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] Common Base URL: file:/C:/academia-server-5.1.0/common/
06:35:50,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] Common Library URL: file:/C:/academia-server-5.1.0/common/lib/
06:35:50,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Name: default
06:35:50,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Base Dir: C:\academia-server-5.1.0\server
06:35:50,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Base URL: file:/C:/academia-server-5.1.0/server/
06:35:50,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Config URL: file:/C:/academia-server-5.1.0/server/default/conf/
06:35:50,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Home Dir: C:\academia-server-5.1.0\server\default
06:35:50,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Home URL: file:/C:/academia-server-5.1.0/server/default/
06:35:50,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Data Dir: C:\academia-server-5.1.0\server\default\data
06:35:50,743 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Library URL: file:/C:/academia-server-5.1.0/server/default/lib/
06:35:50,759 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Log Dir: C:\academia-server-5.1.0\server\default\log
06:35:50,759 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Native Dir: C:\academia-server-5.1.0\server\default\tmp\native
06:35:50,759 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Dir: C:\academia-server-5.1.0\server\default\tmp
06:35:50,759 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Deploy Dir: C:\academia-server-5.1.0\server\default\tmp\deploy
06:35:50,759 DEBUG [ServerImpl] Shutdown hook added Thread[JBoss Shutdown Hook,5,jboss]
06:35:50,790 DEBUG [KernelFactory] Starting JBoss Kernel construction...
06:35:51,133 DEBUG [KernelFactory] Completed JBoss Kernel construction.  Duration: 343 milliseconds
06:35:52,131 DEBUG [ServerImpl] Already in start, ignoring duplicate start
06:35:52,131 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting Microcontainer, bootstrapURL=file:/C:/academia-server-5.1.0/server/default/conf/bootstrap.xml
06:35:52,506 DEBUG [SaxJBossXBParser] Created parser: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl@175b1, isNamespaceAware: true, isValidating: true, isXIncludeAware: true
06:35:52,521 DEBUG [SaxJBossXBParser] http://xml.org/sax/features/validation set to: true
06:35:52,521 DEBUG [SaxJBossXBParser] http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces set to: true
06:35:52,521 DEBUG [SaxJBossXBParser] http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/dynamic set to: true
06:35:52,631 DEBUG [SaxJBossXBParser] Created parser: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl@175b1, isNamespaceAware: true, isValidating: true, isXIncludeAware: true
06:35:52,646 DEBUG [ServerImpl] Failed to start
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error unmarshalling file:/C:/academia-server-5.1.0/server/default/conf/bootstrap.xml
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.xml.BootstrapParser.parse(BootstrapParser.java:60)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.microcontainer.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:123)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:450)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: file:/C:/academia-server-5.1.0/server/default/conf/bootstrap.xml
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:177)
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:119)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.xml.BootstrapParser.parse(BootstrapParser.java:53)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\academia-server-5.1.0\server\default\conf\bootstrap.xml
    at org.jboss.net.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:105)
    at org.jboss.net.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:112)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:173)
    ... 7 more
06:35:52,662 INFO  [ServerImpl] Runtime shutdown hook called, forceHalt: true
06:35:52,693 INFO  [ServerImpl] Shutdown complete
```

That is the output when I try to run the server. Kindly help me find solution to this.

Comment: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\academia-server-5.1.0\server\default\conf\bootstrap.xml

Comment: Please how can this be fixed?

Comment: by either making sure the file exists, or at least, that the path to it is correct

Comment: Please is not in the installation directory, how possible can I restore this file?